# YUM install tigervnc-server fails on RHEL 6.1

Tags: yum, rhel6, vnc

Installing tigervnc-server fails on RHEL 6.1 with the message below.  One person recommended installing all of the xorg-x11 packages, but that gives the same message (below too).

Do I need to add new repositories?  If there is another version of VNC that will install on RHEL I can use that too.

Thanks.

====================================================

```
yum install tigervnc-server
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package tigervnc-server available.
Error: Nothing to do

[root@dean-rhel dean]# yum install xorg-x11*
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do
```

Comment: What is your repository configuration? Are you registered with RHN?

Answer (score 1):

Is your machine looking at the "workstation" repository? That is where I see TigerVNC located:

```
# yum search -v tigervnc | grep -A1 tigervnc
============================ N/S Matched: tigervnc =============================
tigervnc.x86_64 : A TigerVNC remote display system
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-workstation-6
--
tigervnc-server.x86_64 : A TigerVNC server
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-workstation-6
--
tigervnc-server-applet.noarch : Java TigerVNC viewer applet for TigerVNC server
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-workstation-optional-6
--
tigervnc-server-module.x86_64 : TigerVNC module to Xorg
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-workstation-optional-6
```

Answer (score 1):

Your system doesn't have an active entitlement. Register the system with Red Hat Network and assign an active subscription to it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it doesn't like just tigervnc-server.

Try `yum install tigervnc-server*`

I get tigervnc-server.x86_64 as an option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works for me without the asterisk. Are you on a 32-bit box?

Comment: That gives the same error message for me